# JQuery mailcheck on keyboard timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, keyup, onkeyup

I am using this mailcheck code found here: https://github.com/Kicksend/mailcheck That will give you a "suggestion" if you misspell your email incorrectly.

I have one input email box and a div where the suggestion text will appear:

```
<form id="mailcheck-test">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input id="email" type="text">
</form>
<div id="hint"></div>
```

How do I apply a keyup jQuery timer to the input box, then have the mailcheck activate? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Here is my updated code:
    var $email = $('#email');
    var $hint = $("#hint");
    var typingTimer;                //timer identifier
    var doneTypingInterval = 1000;  //time in ms, 5 second for example

```
$('#email').keyup(function(){
    $hint.css('display', 'none').empty();
clearTimeout(typingTimer);
$(this).mailcheck({
    suggested: function(element, suggestion) {
    typingTimer = setTimeout(function(){    
                if(!$hint.html()) {
        // First error - fill in/show entire hint element
        var suggestion = "Yikes! Did you mean <span class='suggestion'>" + "<span class='address'>" + suggestion.address + "</span>" + "@<a href='#' class='domain'>" + suggestion.domain + "</a></span>?";
            $hint.html(suggestion).fadeIn(150);
            } else {
            // Subsequent errors
        $(".address").html(suggestion.address);
        $(".domain").html(suggestion.domain);
            }
            }, doneTypingInterval);
        }
    });
});

$hint.on('click', '.domain', function() {
    // On click, fill in the field with the suggestion and remove the hint
    $email.val($(".suggestion").text());
    $hint.fadeOut(200, function() {
        $(this).empty();
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Okay I have posted my code. I thought I would just insert the mailcheck code into keyup function.

Comment: this will be a problem `if ($('#email').val)`  missing `()` for `val()`

Comment: Hi charlietfi. I have updated my code. I got it to work, but I would like to add a delay to the function. I'm still figuring out how to get that to work.

Comment: have you increased `doneTypingInterval`, try 3000 ?

Comment: create a demo in jsfiddle.net or plunker

Comment: I finally got it working! here is a working version: http://jsfiddle.net/dswizzles/jCWFe/1/

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing your solution. +1 Please remember to post it into an "answer" and select it as the correct answer. You won't get any extra points when you accept your own answer, but future visitors may upvote it and/or your question. However, doing so will certainly help others in the future.  Good work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it working! here is a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dswizzles/jCWFe/1

```
var $email = $('#email');
var $hint = $("#hint");
var typingTimer;                //timer identifier
var doneTypingInterval = 1000;  //time in ms, 5 second for example

$('#email').keyup(function(){
    $hint.css('display', 'none').empty();
clearTimeout(typingTimer);
$(this).mailcheck({
    suggested: function(element, suggestion) {
        if(!$hint.html()) {
        // First error - fill in/show entire hint element
        var suggestion = "Yikes! Did you mean <span class='suggestion'>" + "<span class='address'>" + suggestion.address + "</span>" + "@<a href='#' class='domain'>" + suggestion.domain + "</a></span>?";
        typingTimer = setTimeout(function(){                  
            $hint.html(suggestion).fadeIn(150);
        }, doneTypingInterval);
        } else {
        // Subsequent errors
        $(".address").html(suggestion.address);
        $(".domain").html(suggestion.domain);
        }
        }
    });
});

$hint.on('click', '.domain', function() {
    // On click, fill in the field with the suggestion and remove the hint
    $email.val($(".suggestion").text());
    $hint.fadeOut(200, function() {
        $(this).empty();
    });
    return false;
});
```